# perl - Trying to use a while loop to ask the user if they want to do that again

Tags: perl, loops, factorial

(New to perl)
I have a small perl program that calculates factorials. I'd like to use a while loop so that after the user gets a result, they will be asked "Calculate another factorial? Y/N" and have Y run the code again & have N end the program.

Here's my code:

```
print"Welcome! Would you like to calculate a factorial? Y/N\n";

$decision = <STDIN>;

while $decision == "Y";
{
    print"Enter a positive # more than 0: \n";

    $num = <STDIN>;
    $fact = 1;

    while($num>1)
    {
        $fact = $fact * $num;
        $num $num - 1;
    }

    print $fact\n;
    print"Calculate another factorial? Y/N\n";
    $decision = <STDIN>;
}
system("pause");
```

What's giving me trouble is where to put the while loop and how to make the Y/N option work.  I'm also unclear about `system("pause")` and `sleep` functions. I do know that `system("pause")` makes my programs work though.

Comment: Needs a `chomp`, and `==` is a numeric comparison - you probably want `eq`

Comment: When I run it, it immediately closes itself, despite `system("pause");` Do you know why that would happen by looking at the code?

Comment: When I try your very code then I get `Scalar found where operator expected at err.pl line 15, near "$num $num"
 (Missing operator before $num?)
Backslash found where operator expected at err.pl line 18, near "$fact\"
 (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at err.pl line 5, near "while $decision "
syntax error at err.pl line 15, near "$num $num "
Execution of err.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`, i.e. Perl doesn't even get the chance to consider your `system("pause")` line.

Comment: As previously mentioned `Enter a positive # more than 0:` should be `Enter a non-negative integer:`. Zero is a perfectly [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) input, and you don't need to change anything else for it to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is *almost* right, just a few issues:

1. **Please get used to always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your scripts.** They will
   (beyond other things) force you to declare all the variables you use (with `my $num=…;`)
   and warn you about common errors (like typos). Some people consider it a bug that 
   `use strict;` and `use warnings;` aren't turned on by default.
2. When reading a line from STDIN (or some other filehandle) the read line will contain the
   trailing newline character "\n". For your comparison to work you must get rid of that using
   the [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function.
3. There are two different sets of comparison operators in Perl: one for strings and one for numbers.
   Numbers are compared with `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=`. For strings you must use
   `lt` (less-than), `gt`, `le` (less-or-equal), `ge`, `eq`, and `ne`. If you use one of the number
   operators on strings Perl will try to interpret your string as a number, so `$decision == "Y"`
   would check whether `$decision` is `0`. If you had `use warnings;` Perl would have noticed you.
   Use `$decision eq "Y"` instead.
4. The outer `while` loop had a trailing `;` just after the comparison which will give you an endless
   loop or a no-op (depending on the content of `$decision`).
5. You forgot the `=` in `$num  = $num - 1;`.
6. You forgot the quotes `"` around `print "$fact\n";`
7. `system("pause")` only works on Windows where `pause` is an external command. On Linux (where
   I just tested) there is no such command and `system("pause")` fails with `command not found`.
   I replaced it with `sleep(5);` which simply waits 5 seconds.

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Welcome! Would you like to calculate a factorial? Y/N\n";

my $decision = <STDIN>;
chomp($decision);    # remove trailing "\n" from $decision

while ( $decision eq 'Y' ) {
    print "Enter a positive # more than 0: \n";

    my $num = <STDIN>;
    chomp($num);
    my $fact = 1;

    while ( $num > 1 ) {
        $fact = $fact * $num;
        $num  = $num - 1;
    }

    print "$fact\n";
    print "Calculate another factorial? Y/N\n";
    $decision = <STDIN>;
    chomp($decision);
}
print "ok.\n";

sleep(5);    # wait 5 seconds
```

Comment: `sleep(5)` is not a suitable replacement for `system("pause")`. Besides, there really isn't need for either with this program.

Comment: Tip: The standard is to use lower-case letters in the prompt, except for the default. that would make the prompt `y/N`. Also, one should accept both the lower-case and upper-case inputs here, so `$decision eq 'Y'` should be `fc($decision) eq 'y'`.

Comment: Tip: `--$num;` would be an alternative to `$num  = $num - 1;`

Comment: Tip: `while ( $num >= 2 )` would be a little more clear than `while ( $num > 1 )`

Comment: @ikegami All your comments are perfectly valid. Indeed, there is room for improvement. I just wanted to give an answer with as little differences to the OP as possible. I presume the `sleep` or `pause` should only prevent Windows from immediately closing the window when the script is double-clicked, so that one can see its output.

Answer (score 0):

Always add `use warnings` and `use strict` to the beginning of your program. 
There are a number of typos in your code that would have been caught by this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


print "Welcome! Would you like to calculate a factorial? Enter 'Y' or 'N': ";

my $answer = <STDIN>;
chomp($answer);

while($answer =~ /^[Yy]$/){
    my $fact = 1;
    print"Enter a positive number greater than 0: ";

    my $num = <STDIN>;
    chomp($num);
    my $number_for_printing = $num;

    while($num > 0){
        $fact = $fact * $num;
        $num--;
    }
    print "The factorial of $number_for_printing is: $fact\n";

    print"Calculate another factorial? Enter 'Y' or 'N': ";
    $answer = <STDIN>;
    chomp($answer);
}

print "Goodbye!\n";
```